# PayPal TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade Issue

Tags: paypal, tls1.2, http-1.1

I keep getting warnings from PayPal about `TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade`, saying that an update is needed. However, I've ran the following tests:

**HTTP/1.1 Test**

`$ curl --head mywebsite.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.9.2
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 16:25:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://mywebsite.com
```

**TLS 1.2 Test**

I ran a [PHP script I found](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update), which I ran on my webserver

`PayPal_Connection_OK`

**ssllabs.com tests**

Protocols supported: `TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2`

HTTP Requests: `https://mywebsite.com/  (HTTP/1.1 200 OK)`

**Questions**

1. Everything looks good. What am I missing?
2. How would PayPal determine that my site needs a TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 update?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a `cURL` issue. `cURL` was defaulting to a TLSv1.x connection and not handshaking to a TLSv1.2 connection. I'd been barking up the wrong tree. The following steps on CentOS resolved my problem:

1. Update the following 3 packages:

`sudo yum update curl libcurl nss`

2. Restart nginx/apache*

`sudo service nginx restart`

`sudo service hhvm restart`

*Replace these with relevant services (e.g. apache, php-fpm, etc...)